# sql query to return the result in one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write the query for existing table data. TABLE_A and TABLE_B has one record but TABLE_C has 2 records. One for Home address and other is for Work address.

So the following query returns 2 records. I am trying to get only one record out of 2 records.

If CITY is NULL, state_id is null for address_type = 1(Home) then get Work(address_type = 2) address. If both are null then get 'Home' address. What is the best way to achieve this functionality.

Thank you for any suggestion.

```
select a.A_ID, a.B_ID, a.A_DESC, b.first_name, b.last_name, c.address_type,  c.city, c.state
from table_A a
left join table_B b on b.B_ID = a.B_ID
left join table_C c on c.B_id = b.B_id
where a.A_ID = 10
```

### TABLE_A

```
A_ID int
B_ID int 
A_Desc  varchar(20)
```

### TABLE_B

```
B_ID int
first_name  varchar(30)
last_name   varchar(30)
```

### TABLE_C

```
C_ID    int
B_ID    int 
address_type    int 
city      varchar(50)
state  int
```

Result:

```
 A_ID     B_ID   A_DESC   first_name  last_name  address_type   city       state
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 10       200    test_     name1        name_last    1            NULL       NULL 
 10       200    test_     name1        name_last    2           City_test    2
```

I want this final result

```
 A_ID     B_ID   A_DESC   first_name  last_name  address_type   city       state
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 10       200    test_     name1        name_last    2           City_test    2
```

Comment: Your requirements don't make logical sense. If both are null there is no home address to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.A_ID, a.B_ID, a.A_DESC, b.first_name, b.last_name,
       coalesce(c1.address_type,c2.address_type) address_type, 
       coalesce(c1.city,c2.city) city, 
       coalesce(c1.state,c2.state) state
from table_A a
left join table_B b on b.B_ID = a.B_ID
left join table_C c1 on c.B_id = b.B_id and c.Address_Type = 1
left join table_C c2 on c.B_id = b.B_id and c.Address_Type = 2

where a.A_ID = 10
```

Comment: This would degrade badly if the work city was `null`, but the work street was not

Comment: @Andomar - Not sure I follow you. The same amount of joins would occur in either case, and there is no "work street" column, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Hehe I just meant you could get the state from one row and the city from another.  For example if you had two rows `1, 'Dallas', 'TX'` and `2, null, 'NY'`; your query would print `2, 'Dallas', 'NY'`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `outer apply` to look up the address with the highest type:

```
select  *
from    table_A a
left join 
        table_B b 
on      b.B_ID = a.B_ID
outer apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    table_C c 
        where   c.B_id = b.B_id
        order by
                case
                when c.address_type = 2 and c.city is not null then 1
                else c.address_type = 1 and c.city is not null then 2
                end
        ) c
where   a.A_ID = 10
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to check if city and state is null for both records.

Comment: sometimes Work address is null, then I want Home address.

Comment: Aha, answer edited so that it prefers a non-null work address

Answer (score 0):

Just build this logic into your join condition for left joins to tables b and c.

> If CITY is NULL, state_id is null for address_type = 1(Home) then get Work(address_type = 2) address. If both are null then get 'Home' address

Answer (score 0):

the general technique:

```
select distinct a.A_ID
, a.B_ID
, a.A_DESC
, b.first_name
, b.last_name
, coalesce(home.address_type, work.address_type)
, coalesce(home.city,work.city)
, coalesce(home.state, work.state) 
from table_A a 
left join table_B b on b.B_ID = a.B_ID 
left join table_C home on home.B_id = b.B_id and home.address_type = 1
left join table_C work on work.B_id = b.B_id and home.address_type = 2
where a.A_ID = 10
```

Comment: Isn't that pretty much the same answer as mine?